# validating a regression model

Tags: regression, dataset, validation

I want to build a regression model to predict daily income from customers. I have 2 problems:
1. Choosing data for the training set - do I use daily income from 1 month ago, 6 month ago etc.
2. How do I validate the model - I can use the model to predict the income from the customer on the first day, the second day etc. On some days the model has a small prediction error and on other days large error therefor I do not know how to validate the model.

Help please!

Answer (score -2):

random sample for training set.
build separate regression models for different days to start. Ideally you would want to do growth curve within customers.
validate all models separately. 
If you want to use one model - average prediction error plus information about different rates of errors across days.